# Why is $\langle{\dot A}A^* \rangle=0$ for dynamical variable $A$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-statistics

In page 179 of Hansen and McDonald's book, Theory of Simple Liquids, 3rd edition, 2006, an identity of correlation functions was deduced.

[image]

Here $C_{AB}(t)$ is the time correlation function between dynamical variables. My question is how to get $\langle{\dot A}A^* \rangle=0$ after $\langle{\dot A}B^*\rangle=0$?

if $B=A$,  $\langle{\dot A}A^* \rangle=-\langle A{\dot A^*}\rangle=-{\langle{\dot A}A^* \rangle}^*$ . So if $\langle{\dot A}A^* \rangle$ is a complex number, e.g., $a+bi$, then $a+bi=-(a+bi)^*$, what we get is only $a=0$, while $b$ can be any real number. This is different from $\langle{\dot A}A^* \rangle=0$.

I wonder if the statement that $A$ is a dynamical variable can give any restriction on the correlation function $\langle{\dot A}A^* \rangle$ that it should be real number.

Comment: you build the correlators so as to be real (because you identify a measure with one real number). The correlator of $\dot {A}A*$ is the derivative of a real function (the correlator of AA*) so it has no imaginary part.

Comment: @france95 I see. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please use '\langle' and '\rangle' ($\langle$ and $\rangle$) instead of '<' and '>' ($<$ and $>$).

Comment: @france95 I checked it again, and I found that as $(\dot A A^∗)′=(AA^∗)+A(\dot A^∗)$, And since $(\dot A A^∗)=(A(\dot A^∗))^∗$,$ (\dot A A^∗)$ can still be a real number even if $(\dot A A^∗)$ is a complex number. Would you please give me more detail explanation? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that there is an extra subtletly. Almost always we choose dynamical variables with a well defined signature $\varepsilon$ under time reversal. This is mentioned at the start of that chapter (in the 3rd edition). This means that (their eqn (7.1.9))
$$
\langle A(t) B^*(0) \rangle = \varepsilon_A \varepsilon_B \langle A(-t) B^*(0) \rangle = \varepsilon_A \varepsilon_B \langle A(0) B^*(t) \rangle .
$$
It follows that the autocorrelation functions are both even and real functions of time (irrespective of whether $\varepsilon_A$ is $+1$ or $-1$). In other words, the above equation shows that
$$
\langle A(t) A^*(0) \rangle =  \langle A(0) A^*(t) \rangle
\quad\Rightarrow\quad 
\langle \dot{A} A^* \rangle =  \langle A \dot{A}^* \rangle
$$
as well as the relation you have seen already from stationarity
$$
\langle \dot{A} A^* \rangle =  -\langle A \dot{A}^* \rangle .
$$
Hence $\langle \dot{A} A^* \rangle=0$, as you wanted.

Comment: I got it this time. Thanks a lot for your help!